# Median from two list always wrong in SPOJ

Tags: c, arrays, list

**Problem**?
Given two ordered lists of positive numbers, print the median of the numbers.

**Input**
There are three lines of input. The first line contains a number n, representing the length of each list (Both have the same length). 0 < n <= 2000000.
The second line contains n numbers for the first list, and the third line contains n numbers for the second list. The numbers in the list are separated by single spaces. Each number is a positive integer not bigger than 10 digits.

**Output**
The number found as median of two lists.

**Example**
[Input Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gprf.png)

This code I did tried:

```
//
//  main.c
//  MedianTwoList
//
//  Created by Hendro Prasetyo on 29/09/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Hendro Prasetyo. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int n = 5;

srand( (unsigned int) time(NULL) );
int a[n];
int b[n];
int size = n*2;
int c [size];

int i;
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = rand() % 2000000;
    b[i] = rand() % 2000000;
}

for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i < n) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    } else{
        c[i] = b[i-n];
    }
}

int temp;
for (i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j>0; j--) {
        if (c[j] < c[j-1]) {
            temp = c[j];
            c[j] = c[j-1];
            c[j-1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
if (i%2 == 1) {
    c[i/2];
}else{
    c[(i/2)-1];
}

return 0;
}
```

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: There is no reason to do any of the sizeof operations, since you already know n.  Also there is no reason to create a third list, since you can just walk the two lists until you get halfway through 2*n.

Comment: but if I'm running, the result thought is approximate with the example problem, could you help me with example develope my code?

Comment: Do you have information on the failed test case? (Aside: The program you show obviously isn't the one you submitted to SPOJ, but the supposed output is just the median, not "Median : 41". The results are evaluated automatically, so formatting matters.)

Comment: (The value of `i` equals `size` after the last loop terminates, but it doesn't feel right to use `i` to determine where the middle is. In general, you use too many variables to keep track of the array sizes: `n1`, `n2`, `size`, ´g`. Both arrays have the size ´n`, the large array has size `2*n` and therefore is always of even length, so you don't need the case distiction at the end.)

Comment: I changed that code in my question, how you think? still the wrong answer in SPOJ

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. *"Each number is a positive integer not bigger than 10 digits*". Which data type are you using to hold the value `9,999,999,999`? From here, it looks like `int`. What do you think the maximum `int` value is? I am mystified by the random numbers (and no attempt to read the input data) but they show that you think the maximum data value is `2000000` but that is the **maximum array length**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not read the SPOJ question carefully.